# Installing .rpm wildfly on RHE8 base image in dockerfile

Tags: docker, wildfly

I'm trying to install wildfly to my OCI image which has Rhel8 as the base image with the commands COPY/RUN, I've downloaded wildfly-common-1.1.0-3.el7.noarch.html from rpmfind.net but it seems like it is for RHE7. It doesn't seem like it would be compatible, how should I go about this the correct way?

tried looking for .rpm file for wildfly that works for rhel8 but i can't find it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.